# Oracle Cloud Infrastructure: How do you specify an Availability-domain in a CLI call to create an instance?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have tried all ways to specify the availability domain but keep getting the same error:

```
"code": "InvalidParameter",
"message": "AvailabilityDomain could not be inferred from the Request.
```

I have tried Ucom:AD-1 Ucom:Sanjose-AD-1 ... all the way to the string that is returned with the oci iam availability-domain list command, which in my case was:
"ocid1.availabilitydomain.oc1..aaaaaaaavi2wyd6rjjffu5nzgb3gjq4thy46k7sgw5ibh7mu5sq5fyie6t5a"

I have tried with and without double quotes around the strings. I am completely lost. Please help.

[UPDATE]

Changing the CLI command to say this:

prasanna@prasanna:~/oci$ oci compute instance launch --availability-domain ZbTG:US-SANJOSE-1-AD-1 -c ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaaaa4ykdamkrakpivgazyoc7a2gnykwyaf2e56xohzfejag4mfr3idva --shape VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro --subnet-id subnet-20220121-1006 --ssh-authorized-keys-file authkeys --user-data-file ORTest.sh --image-id Oracle-Linux-7.9-2021.12.08-0

gives a different error: 404: "code": "NotAuthorizedOrNotFound",
"message": "Authorization failed or requested resource not found..

It does not say what failed.  So obviously it looks like the availability-domain needs to be specified the way I have it in the last attempt.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of painstaking work, I solved the problem. For anyone else who is facing similar issues, let me document the process here.

First you need to know your container id which is listed in your config file:  ~/.oci/config and is listed there as: tenancy=ocid1....
Note that here it is called tenancy but in the rest of the CLI calls you provide it as -c ocid1... standing for container id.

Then from that you can list the availability-domain using the command:
oci iam availability-domain list -c ocid1....

I discovered the hard way that what the Oracle Cloud web interface shows does not translate to the actual ocids for the various elements of the oci compute launch ... command and each needs to be discovered with the appropriate list command.

--prasanna

Answer (score 0):

Using the CLI, I would recommend using the AD list command to get the exact specification for the availability domain you want.

`oci iam availability-domain list`

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "compartment-id": "ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaaaa[omitted]mlkq",
      "id": "ocid1.availabilitydomain.oc1..aaaaaaaac7[omitted]f7a",
      "name": "Tdhb:PHX-AD-1"
    },
    {
      "compartment-id": "ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaaaa3fg[omitted]lkq",
      "id": "ocid1.availabilitydomain.oc1..aaaaaaaakemzo4y[omitted]ez3j2hbq",
      "name": "Tdhb:PHX-AD-2"
    },
    {
      "compartment-id": "ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaaaa3fgsh55xv[omitted]lkq",
      "id": "ocid1.availabilitydomain.oc1..aaaaa[omitted]t3mbrlq",
      "name": "Tdhb:PHX-AD-3"
    }
  ]
}
```